# When I try to launch Minecraft on the launcher, it says "already joined game as this user" but I only have one Minecraft account which is on my PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

For some reason when I try to launch Minecraft it says that its already launched on the same account, but I only have Minecraft launcher which is on the PC I'm currently using to type this. I don't share my password with anyone. So I don't know if I got hacked or if its an glitch but if anyone reading this knows why please tell me.

I also don't know if your on something other than Minecraft: Java Edition and if your on maybe bedrock or anything else then its different, by that I mean there's a different way to fix it on bedrock then Java so I'm on Java, and I don't know if its important to to tell what device I'm on if maybe there's a different way to fix it on mobile then PC so I'm on PC if it's important.

Comment: would I be able to see an image of what occurs? It would help me help you. :)

Comment: Have you tried logging off and back on of your account, or tried using Task Manager to check if Minecraft happens to be secretly running in the background?